# How to sort numeric value in file

Tags: java, sorting, file-io

My Input in such a manner in a file

id1 0.44 0.5 #0.13800099498102508
id2 0.44 0.8 #0.22080159196964014
id3 0.44 0.5 #0.15771581712401433
id4 0.44 0.8 #0.22080159196964014
id5 0.11 0.5 #0.04353560295326771
id6 0.11 0.2 #0.017414241181307084

i want to sort value after #, require ans should be in below format

id2 0.44 0.8 #0.22080159196964014
id4 0.44 0.8 #0.22080159196964014
id3 0.44 0.5 #0.15771581712401433
id1 0.44 0.5 #0.13800099498102508
id5 0.11 0.5 #0.04353560295326771
id6 0.11 0.2 #0.017414241181307084

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read a file of "lines" in Java you can use the `Files` class like this:

```
final List<String> l = 
        Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("/some/path/input.txt"));
```

This reads a file and stores each line in a `List`. When you have the `List` of `String` objects you can use a simple `Comparator` and the `Collections.sort`method. Check this code out:

```
final List<String> l = Arrays.asList(
        "id1 0.44 0.5 #0.13800099498102508",
        "id2 0.44 0.8 #0.22080159196964014",
        "id3 0.44 0.5 #0.15771581712401433",
        "id4 0.44 0.8 #0.22080159196964014",
        "id5 0.11 0.5 #0.04353560295326771",
        "id6 0.11 0.2 #0.017414241181307084");

Collections.sort(l, new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(final String o1, final String o2) {
        return o1.substring(o1.indexOf("#") + 1).compareTo(o2.substring(o2.indexOf("#") + 1));
    }
}.reversed());

l.forEach(System.out::println);
```

The output is:

> id2 0.44 0.8 #0.22080159196964014
>   id4 0.44 0.8 #0.22080159196964014
>   id3 0.44 0.5 #0.15771581712401433
>   id1 0.44 0.5 #0.13800099498102508
>   id5 0.11 0.5 #0.04353560295326771
>   id6 0.11 0.2 #0.017414241181307084

The JavaDocs for `Comparator` can be [found here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-java.util.Comparator-).

Note that this solution uses some Java 8 features. If pre Java 8 is used the following comparator can be used instead (notice the `-` sign):

```
Comparator<String> c = new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(final String o1, final String o2) {
        return -o1.substring(o1.indexOf("#") + 1).compareTo(o2.substring(o2.indexOf("#") + 1));
    }
};
```

Another alternative is to use Java 8 Streams. You can combine it with the new `Comparator.comparing` method like this:

```
final List<String> sorted = l.stream()
        .sorted(
                Comparator.<String, String>comparing(
                        (str) -> str.substring(str.indexOf("#")))
                        .reversed())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Note that this does not sort the original `List` but creates a new sorted `List`.

Finally, to save the output to a file again the `Files` class comes to the rescue:

```
Files.write(
        Paths.get("/some/path/output.txt"),
        sorted);
```

You can use the `write` method to write out any `Iterable` object such as the `List` that you just sorted.

Comment: first of all thanx, actually i have this input in file named input.txt so i have to perform sorting and save it to another file suppose out.txt, in my question i had give only six line .. id1 to id6 but this is not fixed input will always vary, so can you help me to get out of this problem

Comment: @PraveenMandloi I mistakenly believed that sorting was the issue. I have added some code for reading/writing files as well.